# Getting xpath of span text

Tags: html, selenium, xpath, firebug

I have a HTML page with an element,

`<div class="selectedCategory" style="" title="">
<div class="selectedCategoryName" style="" title="">Base programming</div>`

The xpath I was trying to use is,

`//*[contains(div,'Base programming') and @class='selectedCategoryName']` - I'm getting no so such element when I try using firebug.

If I use individual xpaths like, 
`//*[contains(div,'Base programming')` and 
`//*[@class='selectedCategoryName']` - It works

But it tends to return so many element on the page. I need a xpath combining the above 2 elements. Please help me out here!

Comment: What is your Usecase? Both the elements looks different to me. Why do you want to combine 2 elements?

Comment: @Dev, As I said, It returns too many elements if I use a single attribute. That's why. One of the element returned tends to be the element that I need. But I just want these two to be combined to serve my purpose.

Comment: please look at the second div tag.. `<div class="selectedCategoryName" style="" title="">Base programming</div>' I would need a xpath for this element.

Comment: Check out my answer and update me.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

These xpaths may help you to find the element with Title "Base programming":

`"//div[@class='selectedCategory']/div[text()='Base programming']"`

OR

`"//div[@class='selectedCategory']/div[@class='selectedCategoryName']"`

Let me know if this helps you.

Comment: But title is an empty attribute. Not sure why it's present. Both of them are not working. The second one works, but there are so many elements under selectedCategoryName.

Comment: @Mathan Great news. Glad that I am able to help you out.

Answer (score 2):

Use the following XPath to select the `div` that contains text 'Base programming' and has class attribute value equals 'selectedCategoryName' :

```
//div[contains(.,'Base programming') and @class='selectedCategoryName']
```

Notice the use of `.` to reference current context element, which in this case is the `div` element.